# Visual Basic 6.0: How to check, if the content of a text box is starting with a particular Character or not?

Tags: validation, input, vb6

I have to put an Input Validation in a text box such that the text does not start with X, Y or Z. 
I don't know how to check this condition in vb6.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the textbox are available as a string its `.Text` property. The `Left$()` function will let you isolate the first character of that string. There are a few ways to test whether that character is one of a selected set; here's one:

```
If Instr("XYZ", Left$(myTextBox.Text, 1)) Then
'  don't validate the contents
End If
```